# How to update user on effective date?

Tags: java, database

We are currently developing a user based web application in java.

A user can have many properties like firstname, lastname, Region (eg. Asia, Europe, US, UK), country, Division, Branch, Product etc.

There are normal CRUD screens for this user with all the above fields.

The add/edit screen for user will also have a date field called effective date. The way this add/edit user is different from normal add/edit in regular CRUD is that the update made to the user will not reflect until the effective date.

Lets say today is 6 April and I add a new user with Region say Asia and effective date 10 April. And now I go and change same user and change his region from Asia to US but effective date say 15 May.

So till 15th may the system should show his region as Asia only and on 15th may his region should change to US automatically.

You can think of it as the user who is working in Asia as on April but from 15th may he is moving to work in US i.e. Region changed from Asia to US effective date 15th may. So till 15th may he should be shown as a user in Asia only.

So I can not just update his region from Asia to us in database as a simple update operation.

And this applies to lot of other fields like division , branch and product as well.

I can not have multiple records for the same user.

**EDIT 1:**

We should also be able to see the user history or the future updates.

Like on the 6 april, I should see that users region will change from 15 May and his division will change from A to B starting 10 may.

I should also be able to delete updates say I come to know later that the proposed transfer of user from Asia to Us effective date 15 may is not going to happen now so  I should be able to delete that  update.

**EDIT 2:-**

Given the above situations, How do I make changes in my original user table and the user change log table?

Say for a user with region asia in the system which is going to change from asia to Us in next few weeks. user will have same update for user. He changes region from asia to user and choose effecftive date as some future date.

Now How do I check if region is changed from asia to us (there can be namy mre fields like region). Shall I do it at the code level or is it possible to do it at the datbase level using triggers etc?

Please help me out with designing the system and database for this.

Comment: Thanks everyone for their answers. Solutions looks good and I need to weigh each one to see whats best in my situation.

Comment: Your Edit2 requirement is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you can implement this system maintaining a **CHANGELOG table** and a **scheduler** which will run at a specific time everyday.

**CHANGELOG table** 
Attributes :

- targetTable
- targetPrimaryKey
- targetColumn
- targetValue
- effectiveDate

Now, whenever a update is made on required fields, insert a corresponding entry in changelog table.

Example,

- targetTable : User
- targetPrimaryKey : 3 (primary row id of user record)
- targetColumn : Region
- targetValue : US
- effectiveDate : 15 May 2012

Now, a scheduler will run every day say(at 12:00 AM) and will check for scheduled changes made to be done that day from CHANGELOG table and make those changes in respective target tables.

**Note : This approach has 2 advantages :**

1. You dont have to maintain two entries for same record.
2. You can target multiple fields(region,division,branch) and multiple tables as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a mapping table as `User_Region` containing the `User_ID`, `Region_ID` and `Change_Date`. `Change_Date` will give when the switch in the region for the user takes place. When the change date is null that could imply that the user is currently in the very region.

Then you can have a list of regions for a `User_ID` along with the dates, which can be displayed according to your convenience.

```
CREATE TABLE User_Regions{
   User_ID INT,
   Region_ID INT,
   Change_Date DATE,
   FOREIGN KEY User_ID REFERENCES User(ID),
   FOREIGN KEY Region_ID REFERENCES Region(ID)
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Historical table would do the trick. That means, having as many history records with *date* column and only treating the one that is closest to current date as current. Otherwise, you have to keep update history in a separate table and have a batch update process to update changes. I would recommend to try to overcome the impediment of unavailability to have multiple records for the same user by getting to normalized structure of user entity: *users* table will have key columns (e.g. id) and a joined table containing the historical updates with the rest of columns.

Comment: As a drawback of separate update process, for consistency you will have to manage lock your user records during the updates, which is not desirable with high loads.

Answer (score 0):

You have two possibilities here:

1. You have a different table that looks like your user table and with an additional column 'validFrom' and then have a cron (quartz) job update every morning.
2. You add the column to your regular user table together with a valid to and change all your queries to reflect that.

As you already said you cannot have multiple records, so 2. would be a bad solution. Stick to 1.

Answer (score 0):

A "pure" data model would be to include a date in the key, and have multiple editions, but there are some issues with changing future events.

I think i would try to model future changes as a list of "operations" and changing a field in the future is in effect scheduling an operation that will modify the field on that date.

The application periodically applies the operations as they become due.

In the GUI, it's trivial to show a list of pending operations, and it's easy to cancel or modify future operations.

You may set up rules to limit or issue warnings for conflicting operations, but if the list is clearly visible, that is less of a problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should use Event statement. Here are the 2 events :

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
    ON SCHEDULE AT DATE_CHANGING
    DO
      UPDATE myschema.mytable SET mycol = mycol + 1;

CREATE EVENT myevent
    CREATE EVENT myevent
    ON SCHEDULE AT DATE_BACKUP
    DO
      UPDATE myschema.mytable SET mycol = mycol - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two approaches:

## Keep all versions in main table

```
| user_name (PK) | effective_date_from (PK) | ...remaining columns
```

In this approach every user is represented by several rows in `User` table but only single row is *current*. In order to find current data you need to add some extra querying:

```
SELECT *
FROM User
WHERE user_name = ?
  AND effective_date >= NOW()
ORDER BY effective_date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

So we are fetching all users with given `user_name` (there are multiple versions of such user with different `effective_date`, so `effective_date` must also be part of primary key). We limit the result to most recent version (but with `effective_date` not in the future).

This approach has several drawbacks:

- what to do with foreign keys? Logically there is only one user in the system
- poor performance, complicating queries
- what to do with outdated versions?

## Pending versions table

Keep the original (main) `User` table schema without any changes and have a second table called `Pending_user_changes`. The latter will also have the same schema + `effective_date` column. If the granularity of changes is one day, write a job (in the database or in the application) that looks for any pending changes that should take effect starting from today and eplace the main table.

I find this solution much cleaner: the primary/foreign keys in main table never change, also the `main` table is not cluttered with old and duplicated data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I think instead of saving entire row in another table it will be better to save o nly changes that are done as I will need to show that in the user logs. Please see I have updated my question.

Comment: @Ashish: I see... so maybe instead of a full row, store only the `id`, `effective_date`, which column/attribute needs to be changed and target value?